# How do I make the face smaller?

Tags: modeling, faces

[image]

When I select something I want to extrude from a face but the shape that I want to extrude is just a little smaller than the face how can i adjust the face extrusion shape to do this? So in otherwords it's a face inside a face but the second is smaller.

[image]

Comment: When taking a screenshot please consider what is and is not relevant to your question. It seems the smallest part of this image is the most relevant and the rest is not.

Comment: Hi Sorry i want to race a smaller face on the top of the landing feet which is why i did the second screen shot as an example.

Answer (score 2):

Try the 'Inset' command, which can be accessed using the <kbd>I</kbd> key when in *Edit* mode. This will create a face nested within the current selection.

Comment: Thanks dude i got it straight away and all is good. It is a minor detail but one side is lower than the other is there a way of selecting one side to lower t all?

Comment: @SimonBlender If this answers your question (same goes for your other questions) you should consider 'accepting' it. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work